# How to fix websocket connection with invalid frame header?

Tags: node.js, peer, peerjs

I am developing a real time chat application, but when i install `peer`, it show me error below. if anyone know the issue. Please guide me.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1234/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Nm9HYV3xCvVy8_w1AAAB' failed: Invalid frame header

**Code**

```
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
  path: "/node",
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use("/peerjs", peerServer);
```

After adding this code, i got error.

[image]

Comment: I also facing same problem. Do you fixed that?

Comment: @MDJahidHasan not yet

Comment: Now I switch to simple-peer from peer. It more better than peerjs.